# Laravel: Method rendor does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to to add pagination to my commentbox but when I add

```
{!! $statuses->rendor() !!}
```

I get this error back:

> ErrorException in Macroable.php line 81:
>   Method rendor does not exist. (View: /home/vagrant/sites/social/resources/views/timeline/index.blade.php)

I searched online and I have seen a few people with this problem but no answers.  From my understanding it's because laravel hasn't been able to find the file where this method is being kept. I would really appreciate it if someone could shed some light on a solution to this. Thanks in advance. I have added my index.blade.php:

```
@extends('templates.default')

@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <form role="form" action="{{ route('status.post') }}" method="post">
            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('status') ? ' has-error' : ''}}">
                <textarea placeholder="What's up {{ Auth::user()->getFirstNameOrUsername() }}?" name="status" class="form-control" rows="2"></textarea>
                @if($errors->has('status'))
                    <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('status') }}</span>
                @endif
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Update status</button>
            {{ csrf_field() }}
        </form>
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <!-- Timeline statuses and replies -->
        @if(!$statuses->count())
            <p>Theres nothing in your timeline yet.</p>
        @else
            @foreach($statuses as $status)
            <div class="media">
                <a class="pull-left" href="{{ route('profile.index', [
                    'username' => $status->user->username
                ]) }}">
                    <img class="media-object" alt="{{ $status->user->getNameOrUsername() }}" src="{{ $status->user->getAvatarUrl() }}">
                </a>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="{{ route('profile.index', [
                    'username' => $status->user->username
                ]) }}">{{ $status->user->getNameOrUsername() }}</a></h4>
                    <p>{{ $status->body }}</p>
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                        <li>{{ $status->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</li> <!-- The diffForHumans() function will change the time to like 1 hour ago etc. -->
                        <li><a href="#">Like</a></li>
                        <li>10 likes</li>
                    </ul>


                    <form role="form" action="#" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea name="reply-1" class="form-control" rows="2" placeholder="Reply to this status"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Reply" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            @endforeach
        {!! $statuses->rendor() !!}

            @endif
    </div>
</div>
@stop
```

Comment: Perhaps you meant "render" instead of "rendor"? [The Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/pagination) would suggest this

Comment: Yes that was it. i feel like a total idiot. You were the first to answer so if you want to change your comment to an answer I'll accept it as it was the one that answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

It should be a `->render()` method.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination#displaying-results-in-a-view

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
{!! $statuses->rendor() !!}
```

use this

```
{!! $statuses->render() !!}
```